# How to support older Android stock browsers?

Tags: android, browser

What is the best method to support older Android devices running **stock browser** without owning multiple physical devices?
Im interested in Android 2.x ... 3.x. Is it maybe possible to install older versions to newer devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It don't think it is possible to install older versions of the browser, but it is possible to run any version of android that you would like using the AVD Manager (Android Virtual Device). Using a virtual device on your computer allows you to control the screen size, software version, and many other factors without having to own a physical device. It can be a little slow if you try to run one on an older computer, but it is definitely worth looking into. It can be downloaded with the Android SDK.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it's a decent advice but unfortunately it is painfully slow and the hardware acceleration support (Intel only) starts from 4.3 versions...

Comment: Then I would think that your best bet for this would be to get another phone for developing purposes. You can probably snag one from one of your friends when they get an upgrade. The phone doesn't have to be unlocked to be useable for development purposes.